# python global module installation when using remote SSH extension

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I use remote-SSH to connect the server(ubuntu 20.04) and I find that if I click the button to install the module of python, it is only installed for one user.
For example:

> xxx is not installed,    install?

Then I find that the command in the terminal is :
**pip install -U `module_name` --user**

So I try to add the configuration in `settings.json` and install again.

`"python.globalModuleInstallation": true`

The terminal has no response, however. Is this a bug?
Though I can type the install command in terminal by myself, I still want to know if vscode can install the module globally by itself.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To install it on the global level (for all users) you need to install it as the root user or as an administrator.

In short you must give the admin privileges.

Use sudo for linux or run you VS code as admin.

Running the VScode as admin solved my issue. Give it a try.